Should we do the checking of state of a shared resource atomically?
I want to know whether we should do the checking of the state of a shared-resource atomically or no. e.g. Consider the following code which demonstrates the classic Bounded-Buffer problem;
lock buf_lock = <initially unlocked>
condition producer_CV = <initially empty>
condition consumer_CV = <initially empty>

Producer(item) {
    acquire(&buf_lock);
    while (buffer full) { 
        cond_wait(&producer_CV, &buf_lock); 
    }
    enqueue(item);
    cond_signal(&consumer_CV);
    release(&buf_lock);
}

Consumer() {
    acquire(buf_lock);
    while (buffer empty) { 
        cond_wait(&consumer_CV, &buf_lock); 
    }
    item = dequeue();
    cond_signal(&producer_CV);
    release(buf_lock);
    return item;
}

In particular I want to know whether the statements "buffer full" or "buffer empty" being evaluated and checked atomically in the while-loops or not.
My guess: I think they should be checked atomically because for sake of contradictory assume this scenario:

Only one item exists in the queue
Now some Consumer thread has been signaled and has acquired the lock as well. Now it goes to queue an item from the queue but it's been preempted and got out of the CPU. Now assume another Consumer thread checking if the queue is not empty (notice that it doesn't need to have acquired the lock if we are assuming the checking is not atomic.). It's not empty so it would go to dequeue an item. Obviously we would have a conflict here...


This is fine to me regarding the protection of "buffer full" and "buffer empty": they are always protected, and by the same lock. The lock is acquired before manually, cond_wait can release the lock temporary and then acquire it back (possibly due to spurious wake-up which does not seems to be an issue here), then the other operations are protected by the lock and the wake-up of the other kind of thread cannot be done as long as the lock is not released so having cond_signal inside the lock section is fine.

If you get out the loop, then it means the lock is acquired by the current thread and the condition is false after acquiring the lock (and the above assertion is true), and only one thread can get the lock, you can be sure that the condition is correctly checked (even with spurious wake-up). It does means that there are no other issue but these two properties are I think 100% guaranteed here (with no other code). Btw, you have written both acquire(&buf_lock); and acquire(buf_lock);: only one should be valid. Same for release.

Btw, If the buffer max size is 0, then I think a deadlock is possible, but this violate your hypothesis (i.e. "only one item exists in the queue") so this is fine. I assumed there is at least both 1 consumer and 1 producer running (avoid infinite waits).

what you are saying is that we actually have the lock while checking the state of the buffer right ? Ah yeah right... @JérômeRichard

Put it shortly, the overall conclusion of the reasoning is that, yes, the check is done correctly and atomically (assuming there is no other code than the one shown), and this include the modification of the queue (under the above assumptions). This answers your main question, right?

That being said, your "Now assume [...]" statement seems to change the context/problem: do you assume another code not shown here is running? This part needs to be clarified because the statement "notice that it doesn't need to have acquired the lock [...]" is impossible with the current shown code (this is why I detailed my reasoning/proof). This part also contradict the statement "we actually have the lock while checking the state of the buffer right".

No you are absolutely right. there is no other code. @JérômeRichard
